# how to target current scope element in ng-repeat in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the below code, inside the parent div[class=timeAllot], wherever, when i make the change(on the input buttons such as am, pm, name etc), then, the button div[div class="buttons"] element shoud be visible. At first, when page loads, it should be invisible.

It should not make all the class buttons div as visible when i make change on the first div, it should make only which div i do change. I mean, if i do change on the first 'timeAllot' div then it should only make invisible first div[div class="buttons"]

Problem is now it make all the div element as visible.

on my controller, i have this code:

```
$scope.items = [{hours: 24, place: 'india'}, {hours: 24, place: 'uk'}, {hours: 24, place: 'USA'}];
$scope.dataItems = ['Items1', 'Item2', 'Item3'];

$scope.displaySaveCancel = false;

$scope.checkthiStuff = function(indexValue){
    console.log("Check this stufff...", indexValue);
    $scope.displaySaveCancel = true;

};
```

in html

```
<div class="timeAllot" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-change="checkthiStuff($index)">

    Name: <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"/>

    <div class="infos" ng-repeat="data in dataItems">
       AM: <input type="text" name="am" ng-model="am"/>
       PM: <input type="text" name="pm" ng-model="pm"/>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons" ng-show="displaySaveCancel === true">
    <button>save</button>
    <button>cancel</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a plunker to show your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$index` of the current Element,

```
<div class="infos" >
   AM: <input type="text" data-ng-change="checkthiStuff($index)" name="am" ng-model="am"/>
   PM: <input type="text" data-ng-change="checkthiStuff($index)" name="pm" ng-model="pm"/>
</div>   

<div class="buttons" ng-show="currentIndex === $index">
    <button>save</button>
    <button>cancel</button>
</div>
```

In the controller,

```
$scope.currentIndex = -1;
$scope.checkthiStuff = function(indexValue){
    $scope.currentIndex = indexValue; 

};
```

Comment: could you please look at my code, i made some changes on my code.